# connect RatingBar with sql

Tags: java, android, sql-server, sqlite, webserver

I added **Rating Bar** to my android app and I want to

> (when any one rating course in my app its store in **SQL** file and
>   then the **rating Bar** show the new stars )

and make it **online** (when people download app from google play show the new rating and when he add his rate app show new rating etc...)

How can I do that?

[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to access an SQL database, then you'll need to use JDBC. https://www.tutorialspoint.com/jdbc/index.htm

You will need to get a host for the database so that people can use the app on any phone. Once you've set up the database and all the JDBC code, there should be a way to autofill the rating bar with data that is in your database.

If you want to store the ratings on the user's phone, then you can use SQLite instead of MySQL and create a database on the user's phone. This will mean that you don't have to get a database host, but it also means no one else will be able to access the data.

Comment: yup i want to every people to access the database

Comment: Yeah, then you will need to get a database host and use MySQL.